# how to count last date inbox sms in android

Tags: android, date, sms, inbox

I am developing an app in which i want to count the last date total `inbox SMS`. i am using this code

```
TextView view = new TextView(this);
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long last24 = now - 24*60*60*1000;//24h in millis
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(last24)};
String selection = "date" + ">?";
String[] projection = new String[]{"date"};
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null);
String sms = String.valueOf(cur.getCount());
view.setText("Total incoming today SMS  "+sms);
setContentView(view);
```

I am able to count the last 24 hours inbox sms, but I need to count last date inbox sms. like today `Date is 28/02/13` but i want to count total inbox sms of `Date 27/02/13`.

please help me i am new learner thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set selection as `date between date('now', '-1 day') and date('now')`, remove `selectionArgs`

Update:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, "datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') between date('now', '-1 day') and date('now')", null, null);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am not understanding how to implement programmaticaly what are you saying.

Comment: change line 8 to `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, "date between date('now', '-1 day') and date('now')", null, null);`

Comment: seems like date filed is in milliseconds from currentTimeMillis(), the answer could be: `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, "datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') between date('now', '-1 day') and date('now')", null, null);`

Comment: Great last one working correctly. thank you from my bottom of heart, really you are very kind. thanks again